How do I get unique values in my system.array?
How do I get unique values in my array below?
$serverenv = 'computername,env
server1,prod
server1,
server2,prod,
server2,prod' | convertfrom-csv 

$serverenv | where-object { $_.Env -ne $null -and $_.Env -ne "" }

This is the output
computername env 
------------ --- 
server1      prod
server2      prod
server2      prod

This is the desired output
computername env 
------------ --- 
server1      prod
server2      prod

I tried
$serverenv | select Get-Unique
$serverenv | Get-Unique


a note: when making a comparison to $null it's better to have $null on the left side of the comparison: $null -ne $_.env in your example. Because Powershell might use MAGIC to attempt convert the right-side element to the type of the left-side which can have unforeseen effect(an empty string is NOT a $null)

You can use Sort-Object -Unique:
$serverenv |
    Where-Object { -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.env) } |
    Sort-Object computername, env -Unique


Just $serverenv | Sort-Object computername -Unique will work for this.

depends on env having other values than prod or empty. question isn't clear @iRon

You should group all items by same property name.
Then for each group of same name to select only one object using...
$serverenv | Group-Object -Property 'ComputerName' | ForEach-Object {
       $_.Group | Select-Object -First 1
}

If you need like to skip values with empty "env", like you can add this logic inside the foreach scriptblock.
For example, filter all object with empty env property.
(Where object's property env not equal null)
$serverenv | Group-Object -Property 'ComputerName' | ForEach-Object {
       $_.Group | Where-Object -Property 'env' -ne $null | Select-Object -First 1
}

